# storing a pointer into a map

Tags: c, pointers, dictionary

This is a rough idea of what I am doing:

```
Map map;
create_map(map); //initialize map
Value x,y;
while(...){
  ...
  x = ...;
  y = ...;
  put(map, x, (void *) &y);
  ...
}
```

Map is of type {Value, (void *)}.  The Map is custom written but I did not write it.  I am trying to figure out where it is defined and will update if I find it.  All the map does is store the association of a Value and a (void *) in a struct of some sort.

I think what is going on is that the value, y, inserted into the map is not getting the value I want.  It is storing whatever value y is after the while loop executes.  I want the address of each iteration to be different and pointing to a different version of y.

So with the code above, for any key X in the map, they all point to the same value.  I want them to point to different values.

Comment: As your functions `create_map` and `put` are not a part of C so all bets are off.

Comment: Without an idea of what `Map` is and what `create_map` or `put` does, it would be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: The Map was custom created but I did not create it.  I am trying to find where it is declared.  The map just associates a Value with a (void *) and stores this association in a struct of some sort.

Comment: The answer from @DanielFleishman looks right.  The Map is not copying the things inserted into it, so if you are using the same memory to create each item before `put` they will get overwritten later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you will need to allocate different copies of "Value", something like this:

```
Map map;
Value x;
Value *y;
create_map(map); //initialize map
while(...){
  ...
  x = ...;
  y = malloc(sizeof(Value));
  *y = ...;
  put(map, x, (void *) y);
  ...
}
```

Just don't forget to deallocate at the end.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to do I just couldnt think of it atm.